# Why can't i use something like "OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer.Items;"?

Tags: delphi, outlook

//Any help?
//I use Delphi + Outlook

> Why can't i use something like
>   "OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer.**Items**;"
>   [Want to Access all Items in ActiveExplorer]
>
> Why only make MailItems available through
>   OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer.**Selection**
>   [Want to access all Items ActiveExplorer]

```
Procedure TFLV.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
CONST
olFolderInbox = $00000006;   //...
VAR                          //Declaring VARs
OutlookApp,                  //The outlook App
MailItem,                    //A MailItem
OLEFolderInbox : OLEVariant; //...

XX  : Integer;
Itm : TListItem;
begin
ListView1.Clear;

OutlookApp := GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application');

//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
//Problem - The following Display all the entries in a 
//different order from Outlook's InBox!
//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
TRY////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
{} //OLEMailItems := OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer.Items; 
{} //Does not exist so I had to use this:
{}
{} OLEFolderInbox := OutlookApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);
{}                OLEMailItems := OLEFolderInbox.Items;
{} FOR XX := 1 to OLEMailItems.Count DO
{} BEGIN
{} Itm := ListView1.Items.Add;
{} Itm.Caption := DateTimeToStr(OLEMailItems.Item[XX].ReceivedTime );
{} Itm.SubItems.Add(  OLEMailItems.Item[XX].Recipients.Item[1].Name);
{} Itm.SubItems.Add(  OLEMailItems.Item[XX].SenderName             );
{} Itm.SubItems.Add(  OLEMailItems.Item[XX].Subject                );
{} Itm.ImageIndex := -1;
{} END;
{}     
{}FINALLY
{}   OLEMailItems   := VarNull;
{}   OLEFolderInbox := VarNull;
{}   OutlookApp     := VarNull;
{}END;/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



{}//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
{}//Problem: Why must I             "ActiveExplorer.SelectAllItems"  !!!!!
{}//         Why not something like "OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer.Items"!!!!!
{}//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
{}TRY/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
{}                                OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer.SelectAllItems;
{}                OLEMailItems := OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection;
{}
{} FOR XX := 1 To OLEMailItems.Count DO
{} BEGIN
{} Itm := ListView1.Items.Add;
{} Itm.Caption := DateTimeToStr(OLEMailItems.Item[XX].ReceivedTime    );
{} Itm.SubItems.Add(     OLEMailItems.Item[XX].Recipients.Item[1].Name);
{} Itm.SubItems.Add(     OLEMailItems.Item[XX].SenderName             );
{} Itm.SubItems.Add(     OLEMailItems.Item[XX].Subject                );
{} Itm.ImageIndex := -1;
{} END;
{}     
{}FINALLY
{}     OLEMailItems   := VarNull;  // := Nothing
{}     OLEFolderInbox := VarNull;  // := Nothing
{}     OutlookApp     := VarNull;  // := Nothing
{}END;///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

end;
```

Comment: Ask Microsoft. As far as I can see an Outlook Explorer object does not have an Items property or method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860356.aspx  And why would it be issue if you have to use syntax X or Y to get your results?

Comment: If you're asking why you can't use `OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer.Items`, it's because it doesn't exist, and you can't use non-existent properties. If you're you asking us to speculate on why Microsoft decided not to provide an `Items` property, or why they decided to only make `MailBox` available? If so, we can't help. Contact the Microsoft Office team and ask them; you can find them at http://www.microsoft.com/office.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items` - you will get all the items in the currently displayed folder.